# Twig: Override elements with embed

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I have the following template structure and I want to override a block with embed:

**base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      {% embed 'header.html.twig' %}
         {% block content %}{% endblock %}
      {% endembed %}
   </body>
</html>
```

**header.html.twig**

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

**page.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
   <p>Some content</p>
{% endblock %}
```

If I load the page.html.twig with my controller now I thought it should display "Some content" but it doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea what I did wrong?

Comment: You need a block `content` in `base.html.twig`. The one mentioned inside the embed tag does not count. If you want to manipulate the header from page, you could add a (for example) `header_wrapper` block around the embed tag.

Answer (score 0):

"The embed tag combines the behaviour of include and extends. It allows you to include another template's contents, just like include does. But it also allows you to override any block defined inside the included template, like when extending a template."
[twig document about embed block](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html)

You can use import or include. I recommend include fot this state